# DEBUG error expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, asn.1

I am integrating asn1c code into Xcode project. Currently I am getting this error:

```
/asn1c/converter-sample.c:76:1: error: expected identifier or '('
DEBUG(const char *fmt, ...) {
^
```

Source code:

```
/* Debug output function */
static inline void
DEBUG(const char *fmt, ...) {  // 76th line
    va_list ap;
    if(!opt_debug) return;
    fprintf(stderr, "AD: ");
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

What is the way to fix this build error?

I did look into similar questions in StackOverflow, but could not found answer which could help me.

Comment: maybe somewere there is a `#define DEBUG 1` or something similar?

Comment: @Ramis  It is a bad idea to use all capital letters for function names. Rename the function. It seems there is defined a macro with the same name. Or use #undef DEBUG

Comment: As always in cases like these, read the *preprocessed code* to make sure you know what the compiler is actually seeing. With gcc, this is the `-E` option. There's probably a "debug build" flag that sets `DEBUG` to some constant using the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think definitely there is a redeclaration of DEBUG or #defined as @ammoQ was saying. please check the other location and see that there are no same RE declarations
just change it as DEBUG1 AND try it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone like me.
I was facing this problem recently while integrating a c project in XCode 12, in my case, it was showing an error in ***DEBUG = 0,*** line.

```
typedef enum {
    DEBUG = 0,
    INFO,
} LogLevel;
```

I came to know in the build settings of my project, in section ***Apple Clang Preprocessing***, subsection ***Preprocessor Macros***, following value was set

> DEBUG=1

I removed it and problem solved.